# What's the origin of the "h" in "Ah"? (Qual a origem do "h" no fim de interjeições como "Ah"?)

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, origem, interjeições

I've noticed that "ah" is the only time when an `h` is used at the end of a word/interjection. Based in what I know, there's no "ah" without the `h` as an interjection.
Putting an `h` at the end is common in other languages , as in English ("oh", "ah", etc.). But in Portuguese, e.g. "ó" doesn't have an `h` at the end (or this is not the standard, at least).

Also there's "ih" and "uh".

This `h` at the end of these interjections come from Portuguese or are "imported" from another language(s)?

---

Pelo que percebo, "ah" é o único caso em que se usa um `h` no fim de uma palavra/interjeição. Que eu saiba não existe "ah" sem o `h` como uma interjeição.
Colocar um `h` no fim é comum em outros idiomas, como no inglês ("oh", "ah", etc.). Mas no português, como por exemplo "ó" não usa `h` no final (ou pelo menos não é esse o padrão).

Tem também "ih" e "uh".

Esse `h` no final dessas interjeições é do próprio português mesmo ou é "importado" de outra(s) língua(s)?

Comment: `oh` decididamente existe. `ó` é mais usado para chamar alguém.

Comment: *Ah, afinal não foste ao evento.* Excelente pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Atualmente existem todas as combinações possíveis: [*ah*](http://www.aulete.com.br/ah), [eh](http://www.aulete.com.br/eh), [ih](http://www.aulete.com.br/ih), [oh](http://www.aulete.com.br/oh) e [*uh*](http://www.aulete.com.br/uh) (ver no Aulete). ***Ah*** e ***oh*** são antigas e já vêm, com *h*, do latim, em que também se escrevia simplesmente *o* em lugar de *oh* [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/oh). No entanto, em português, as grafias mais antigas são sem *h:* *a, o* e *oo*. Só passamos a encontrar o *h* do século XVI em diante; sistematicamente no caso do *ah*, esporadicamente no caso do *oh*; as grafias *o* e *oo* mantiveram-se até ao século XVIII. As restantes interjeições aparecem, com frequência apreciável, na literatura do século XIX [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp); imagino que o *h* tenha sido por analogia com *ah* e *oh*.

Há uma diferença entre ***oh*** e ***ó***, que está muito bem explicada no [Dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/oh-ou-o/). *Oh* é uma interjeição de surpresa, desgosto, felicidade, etc. Na fala é seguida de pausa, que se pode indicar na escrita por ponto de exclamação, vírgula ou reticências

> Oh! que coisa linda.
>
> Eu a chamá-lo e ele, oh! a fingir que não ouvia.

*Ó* é também uma interjeição, mas tem função vocativa, para chamar a atenção:

> Ó João, passa aí o vinho.
>
> Ó meu malandreco, isso não se faz!

Segundo o linguista britânico Roger Fowler, citado no [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=oh), também no inglês há uma tendência para usar *oh* e *o* desta maneira: *oh* como interjeição independente, e *o* procliticamente, “inclinado” sobre a palavra seguinte, como em *ó João, vem cá*. Encontram-se no entanto em muitos livros em português *oh* em lugar de *ó*.

---

Segundo o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), *ah* encontra-se no português a partir do século XIII, e *oh* a partir do XIV. Mas o Houaiss indica as primeiras ocorrências de uma palavra independentemente da grafia. Nós encontramos *ah* em transcrições atuais de cantigas de escárnio e maldizer do século XIII, mas nas cópias mais antigas que encontrei, do Cancioneiro de 1527 da Biblioteca Nacional, o que se encontra é simplesmente *a*. Vejam por exemplo esta cantiga de Gil Peres Condes (que tem o til na vertical; [q̃ era abreviação de *que*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%CC%83); *senhor* era masculino e feminino no português antigo):

[image]
[Cancioneiro de 1572](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/manuscrito.asp?cdcant=1560&cdmanu=3091&nordem=1&x=1), depois [transcrição da Universidade Nova de Lisboa](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=1560&pv=sim) e a minha “tradução”.

Ou comparem esta transcrição desta [cantiga de Mem Rodrigues Tenoiro e Julião Bolseiro](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=377&pv=sim) com o [original do Cancioneiro](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/manuscrito.asp?cdcant=377&cdmanu=628&nordem=2&x=2).

Mas a primeira edição d’[Os Lusíadas, 1572](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/342), já traz *ah:*

[image]
[Luís de Camões, *Os Lusíadas*, 1572, canto X, f. 167.](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/342)

---

Por esta altura a grafia *ah* já deveria ser comum, pois [Duarte Nunez de Lião fala dela na sua *Orthograhia da Lingoa Portuguesa* de 1576](http://purl.pt/15/4/res-277-2-v_PDF/res-277-2-v_PDF_24-C-R0150/res-277-2-v_0000_rosto-78v_t24-C-R0150.pdf). O autor oferece também uma explicação fonética para o *h*. Diz ele que o *h* assinala uma “aspiração ou assopro com que se pronunciam as letras a que se ajunta”, acrescentando que no português essa aspiração só se faz sentir nas interjeições *ha ha* e *ah* (original à esquerda; grafia atual à direita):

[image]
[Duarte Nunez de Lião, *Orthograhia da Lingoa Portuguesa*, 1576, f. 8.](http://purl.pt/15/4/res-277-2-v_PDF/res-277-2-v_PDF_24-C-R0150/res-277-2-v_0000_rosto-78v_t24-C-R0150.pdf)

Parece-me que o senhor tem razão: o *ah* de “*ah! minha senhora, que pena*” é diferente do *à* de “*dê isto à minha senhora*”.

---

O *oh* mais antigo que encontrei é de 1590 (minha transcrição à direita):

[image]
[Vasco Mousinho de Castelbranco, “Emblemas, De la musica enemigo”, *Vida e Morte de Santa Isabel Rainha de Portugal*, 1590, f. 102.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=vntfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PT176&dq=oh&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY74m486HSAhVEOxQKHRGrDq0Q6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=oh&f=false)

No entanto o que é comum ainda nesta época é *o* ou *oo*. Mas edições do século XVIII de obras deste período já trazem *oh*. Por exemplo, o *Erros meus, má fortuna…* de Camões vem com *o* numa edição de 1616 e já com *oh* numa de 1739:

[image]
Luis de Camões, *Erros meus*... [edição de 1616](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/324) e [edição de 1739](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YPBFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22Mil%20vezes%20cada%20hora%20me%20mentia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1x4-S7IjSAhXCthoKHcYJCOY4MhDoAQiFATAN#v=onepage&q=%22Mil%20vezes%20cada%20hora%20me%20mentia%22&f=false)

---

Já no *Auto da Alma* de Gil Vicente, encontramos *oo* na edição original de 1561 e *oh* numa edição de 1834:

[image]
Gil Vicente, *Auto da Alma*: [original de 1561](http://purl.pt/252/3/#/16) e edição posterior de [1834](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bNEQAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA192&dq=%22como%20vindes%20pera%20a%20gloria%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIqq3MzaHSAhUESRoKHWIRA7IQ6AEIcDAN#v=onepage&q=%22como%20vindes%20pera%20a%20gloria%22&f=false)

---

Não é de espantar que *ah* tenha substituído *a* no século XVI. A grafia portuguesa medieval era essencialmente fonética; a partir do renascimento foi fortemente influenciada pelos “redescobertos” clássicos gregos e latinos. Foi por exemplo por esta altura que *história* substituiu *estória* [(ver esta minha resposta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/823/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-est%C3%B3ria-e-hist%C3%B3ria/827#827) e que desapareceram *ome* e *omem*, por *homem* [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp). A adoção mais lenta de *oh* deveu-se talvez à coexistência de *o* e *oh* no próprio latim.

Comment: +1 pelas imagens e pela antiguidade dos exemplos.

Comment: @SaraCosta Obrigado. Nesta perguntas sobre origens, quanto mais antigos os exemplos, melhor.

Answer (score 4):

O uso do h após as vogais, quando usado em interjeições, representa um breve alongamento na pronúncia. O uso é limitado a interjeições, não existindo em outras palavras. O h pode ser repetido tantas vezes quanto mais prolongado for o som, como por exemplo:

"Ah!": a fala é curta, como em uma surpresa. Pronuncia-se "AA!".
"Ahhhhhh....": som prolongado, como em um desapontamento; pronuncia-se "aaaaaammm".
"Ahhhhh!!!": um grito muito longo e prolongado, como quem viu um fantasma. Pronuncia-se "AAAAAAAAAAA".

O mesmo pode ser usado com i, o, u...

"ihhhhhhh...." = Usado para expressar desapontamento, pronuncia-se "iiiiiiiiii".

"Ohhhhhhhh..." = Usado para expressar surpresa, pronuncia-se "óóóóóóóó".

O numero de "h" usado na escrita depende do quanto se deseja prolongar na pronúncia.

Com o advento da informática, nos anos 90, os primeiros teclados de computador eram padrão americano (EUA), e não possuíam as teclas em português (ç, ~), não era possível escrever os acentos. Assim, muitas vezes para diferenciar o "á" ou "é" do "a" e "e", usava-se H no final da palavra, como em:

Peh = pé
Babah = babá

Esse uso, entretanto, é recente ( apenas com o advento da informática), e não se confunde com o uso das expressões originais "Ah" que é muito antigo e se confunde com a origem da língua.

Atualmente, a maioria dos teclados e sistemas informatizados possui os acentos (padrão unicode), sendo muito menos utilizadas.

Answer (score -1):

*Pesquisei bastante e achei uma coisa sobre isso...*

Primeiro que antigamente as máquinas de escrever e computadores na maioria das vezes não tinham teclados brasileiros, ou seja, sem acento. Então as pessoas usavam `h` após as palavras para substituir o acento.

Hoje em dia as coisas são mais confusas, conheço bastante gente que usa `h` nos finais das palavras justamente para "parecer mais" com americanos... 
Alguns também usam para dar mais "emoção" as palavras como `ihhhh`, etc.
O resto já são aquelas pessoas que todos nós conhecemos bem, **os inimigos da Língua Portuguesa**

Comment: Em Portugal usamos para mostrar admiração. "Ah ela é francesa, está explicado o sotaque." ou "Oh meu Deus ele fez isso?".

Comment: Acho que até aqui no Brasil bastante gente usa assim também...

Comment: @MarcosSartorato Poderia postar o link?

Comment: Onde eu achei essa informação? Se sim, é um fórum bem bagunçado e com as postagens de 2008...

Comment: Usa-se o eh no lugar de é, ou estah para está, quando não se tem teclado com acentos ou configurado. Usar h para ficar fofo?

Comment: Leia a resposta de novo...