# Qual a diferença entre “estória” e “história”?

Tags: ortografia, significado

Eu sempre achei que sabia quando usar um e outro. Um dia li algo que não era o que eu pensava. Afinal, quando eles são intercambiáveis ou quando tem significado diferente?

Dá para dizer que a tradução do inglês é direta sempre?

> story → estória
>
> history → história

Comment: Sim, esse é uma boa pergunta! Acho que você cria uma estória mas relata uma história. Sendo assim, seria basicamente igual inglês - A story is created, a history is related.

Comment: É o que eu achava :) Parece que não é.

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta, com citações antigas. Quando escrevi a resposta original ainda não tinha descoberto o Corpus do Português. A palavra *historia* aparece no século XVI. O que se usava antes era sobretudo *estoria*, mas com o mesmo significado. A distinção de *estória - fictício* e *história - real* foi uma invenção do século XX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> As duas grafias existem há muito tempo e antigamente havia uma
>   diferença significativa entre elas. A palavra estória é muito antiga
>   na língua portuguesa, acredita-se que tenha surgido no século XIII.
>   Empregava-se a forma estória quando a intenção era se referir às
>   narrativas populares ou tradicionais não verdadeiras, ou seja,
>   ficcionais. Já a palavra história era utilizada em outro contexto,
>   quando a intenção era se referir à História como ciência, ou seja, a
>   história factual, baseada em acontecimentos reais.
>
> A palavra estória é considerada um tipo de arcaísmo, isto é, aquelas
>   palavras que, por serem muito antigas, quase não usamos mais. Ela era
>   utilizada quando ainda não havia uma grafia uniformizada para as
>   nossas palavras, mas, em 1943, com a vigência do nosso sistema
>   gráfico, a Academia Brasileira de Letras entendeu que não deveria mais
>   haver diferenças entre história e estória e que a palavra história
>   deveria ser empregada em qualquer situação, seja para nomear
>   narrativas ficcionais ou reais.

**Exemplos:**

- *A mãe contou uma **história** para o filho dormir.*
- *Os amigos adoram contar **histórias** de pescador.*

<sub>(Antigamente, a forma correta a ser empregada nesses exemplos abaixo ↓ era *estória*.)</sub>

- *Os alunos irão aprender sobre a **história** da Língua Portuguesa.*
- *A turma ouviu atenta a **história** da vida de Machado de Assis.*

---

> Já no Inglês, essa diferença ainda persiste, e com umas regras a mais. History continua significando a ciência histórica. Mas story pode significar: obra de ficção que narra uma série de eventos relacionados entre si; piso, andar ou pavimento; e matéria jornalística.

**Exemplos:**

- **The Empire State Building has 102 stories of office space.**
  (*O “Empire State Building” tem 102 andares ocupados por escritórios.*)
- Email this story.
  (*Envie essa matéria por e-mail.*)
- **However, this is a story with a happy ending.** (ABC News)
  (*Entretanto, essa é uma história que tem um final feliz.*)
- Founded in the 17th century, Boston is steeped in history. (USA Today)
  (*Fundada no século XVII, Boston está repleta de história.*)

**Fontes:**

http://www.escolakids.com/historia-ou-estoria.htm

http://www.teclasap.com.br/falsas-gemeas-history-x-story/

http://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/story-x-history-qual-a-diferenca-t4154.html

Comment: A *estória* da escolakids que tu citas é pura ficção. *Estoria* foi usado nos séculos XIV e XV, mas com o significado de relato verídico. Nessa altura ainda não se usava a palavra *historia*. Vê a minha resposta.

Answer (score 16):

Eu também pensei em tempos que *história* era o estudo do passado ou um relato de acontecimentos verídicos, e *estória* era uma narrativa ficcional. Mas não é bem assim. [***História*** segundo o Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/hist%C3%B3ria) e o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa engloba quer o estudo do passado e relatos verídicos quer as histórias da carochinha. O [Aulete também tem o verbete ***estória***](http://www.aulete.com.br/est%C3%B3ria), como narrativa ficcional, mas remete para *história*, que diz ser a forma preferida. O Dicionário da Academia nem sequer tem *estória*.

Finalmente, na [*triste história de estória*](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/06/a-triste-historia-de-estoria/) o Prof. Cláudio Moreno desvendou-me o mistério. Explica ele que *estória* aparece em textos medievais, tal como *hestoria, istoria*, e *estorea*. Mas qualquer destas palavras tanto pode significar relato verídico como fictício. Era simplesmente a grafia que não tinha estabilizado. Na escrita de Camões a grafia já estabilizara em *historia*. No século XX puseram-lhe o acento. Foi em 1919 que o intelectual brasileiro [João Ribeiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_Batista_Ribeiro_de_Andrade_Fernandes) propôs a tal distinção entre *estória* e *história*. O novo termo foi popularizado em 1967 pelo autor brasileiro [João Guimarães Rosa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guimar%C3%A3es_Rosa), mas nunca teve aceitação universal, como podemos ver no Aulete digital.

Posto isto fiz a minha própria pesquisazinha no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), e os resultado estão na tabela abaixo. Basicamente *historia* aparece no século XVI e substitui *estoria* e outras variantes.

**Número de ocorrências no Corpus do Português**

```
           Século   XIII   XIV    XV   XVI   XVII
Estoria(s)            2    382   407    22     1
Estorya(s)            0    234    10     4     0
Estorea(s)            0      0    11     8     0
Hestoria(s)           1      0    14     0     0
Historia(a)           0      0     2   356   386
```

A única ocorrência de *estoria* no século XVII é elucidativa. É de Bento Pereira, *Thesouro da Lingoa Portuguesa*, 1697 [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/):

> Estoria. Vide Historia

Ou seja, tratava-se simplesmente de duas variantes gráficas da mesma palavra. Em praticamente todos os casos que vi, estas palavras designam relatos que os autores acreditam ser verdadeiros. A exceção são [fábulas de Esopo, econtradas num manuscrito do século XV](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_Livro_de_Esopo), onde curiosamente se emprega *hestoria* (possivelmente uma variante surgida aquando da transição de *estoria* para *hisoria*). Eis alguns exemplos, como uma fábula completa no fim:

> Ora leixaremos de fallar desto e tornaremos ao conto dos reis de Navarra pera hyrmos per esta ***estorya*** dos reis de Navarra em dyante. E despois tornaremos aos reis d'Aragom e de França e de Castella e de Leom e per qual guisa foron juntos os reynos de Castella e de Leon. Conta a ***estoria*** dos reis de Navarra que este rey dom Garcia, de que avemos dicto, foy filho de dõ Sancho, o Mayor. ([*Crónica Geral de Espanha*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_Geral_de_Espanha_de_1344), 1344.)
>
> E por nom fazer longo prolego farei aqui começo em este virtuoso senhor, do qual veeo o valente e muito virtuoso conde estabre dom Nuno Alverez Pereira. E assi, de hi em diante, siguiremos nossa ***estoria***. ([*Crónica do Condestável Nuno Alvarez*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_do_Condest%C3%A1vel), 1431)
>
> Os homens prinçipais que com elle hião forão Gonçalo Rodriguez Caldeira, seu irmão João Caldeira, Simão Pedroso da Castanheda, Christouão Foreiro, Diogo Lobo de Sousa, que depois foi capitão de bardes, e outros que se nomearão pelo descurço da ***estoria*** que fizerão feitos abalisados. (Diogo do Couto, 1542-1616, [*Da Asia, Década VIII*](http://purl.pt/7030/3/l-79460-p/l-79460-p_item3/index.html#/4).)

[***O Livro de Esopo: XLVI [o leão e o rato]***](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_Livro_de_Esopo/O_le%C3%A3o_e_o_rato)

> Diz que foy hũa vez hũu leom que jazia em hũu mato de so hũa fremosa verdura. E os rratos ssobiam per çima d’elle, pera escarneçerem d’elle; e elle tomou hũu e queria-ho matar. E ho rrato lhe rrogou que lhe nom fezesse mall, ca nom seria ssa homrra, dizem[do q]ue [em] algũu tempo lhe poderia fazer algũu boo s[erviço]. E o leom o leixou, e nom lhe fez mall. [E ho] rrato lhe deu muytas graças.
>
> E d’hi a [pouco] tempo cayo o leom em hũu laço que lhe fezerom os caçadores pera o filhar: e o leom começou de braadar altas vozes. E este rrato, a que ell perdoára a morte, lhe disse:
>
> — Quamtos leões no mundo ssom nom te podem d’aquy liurar! Mays eu, que ssom a mais vill alimalia do mundo, pella graça e bem que me fezeste, te quero liurar.
>
> E loguo ssobio e rroeo ha corda que tijnha no pescoço e liurou-[ho] d’aquelle prijguo. E o leom veem[do]-ss’ em liberdade, deu muytas graças ao rrato, e foy-sse sseu caminho.
>
> Em esta ***hestoria*** o doutor emssina os grandes homẽes do mumdo e os poderosos, que nom despreçem os pequenos que ham pequeno poder, ca nom he nhũu homem de tam pequeno poder que nom possa seer proueytoso em algũu tempo aaquell que he gramde e poderoso. Tall seruiço lhe póde fazer hũu homem pequeno, que lh’o nom póde fazer hũu gramde.

Comment: Excelente serviço público, aliás, como sempre! Em qualquer caso, para ter o cérebro e a memória bem organizados, sigo o exemplo do intelectual João Ribeiro. Gosto da sua proposta, é clara, julgo que tem lógica, e é semanticamente correta. Até pela similitude com o Inglês, onde essa distinção semântica, de facto, existe.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, obrigado. Usava-se em tampos antigos também "crónica", essa, creio, designava sempre acontecimentos reais. Li algures (posso procurar se estiveres interessado), que na época medieval se fazia a distinção entre estória/história/etc., sempre centrada nalguma pessoa, e crónica, referente a um período. Assim, uma crónica de D. João I seria sobre os acontecimentos principais durante o seu reinado, evolvendo ou não o rei, enquanto a estória/história de D. João I seria centrada no próprio rei.