# História x estória, um conflito histórico

Tags: português-brasileiro

Sempre tive está dúvida, entre História e Estória,
qual é a diferença entre ambos e quando usar ?

Comment: Hiroyuki, vê se [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/823/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-est%C3%B3ria-e-hist%C3%B3ria) e as duas respostas que lá estão respondem à tua dúvida. Como as duas respostas que lá estão divergem terás de ter espírito crítico ;)