# Por que, na internet, usamos a letra H para representar um acento agudo?

Tags: ortografia, origem

Na internet, é normal escrevermos algumas palavras sem acento, até mesmo em função do layout do teclado que é utilizado. Em alguns casos, a letra **h** é usada como se fosse "fazer o trabalho" do acento agudo.

Ex.: `é = eh` `está = estah` `só = soh`

Por que temos este costume?

Comment: Relacionada: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/683/whats-the-origin-of-the-h-in-ah-qual-a-origem-do-h-no-fim-de-interjei%c3%a7%c3%b5

Comment: Em Portugal não há qualquer hábito de usar "h" para significar acento agudo. Muito melhor não escrever nada ou algo como a', e', etc

Comment: Na computação sempre usamos o h para esse fim, décadas antes da internet. O motivo vem da necessidade de enfatizar sílabas tônicas no lugar do acento,  nos sistemas sem suporte a Unicode (https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

Comment: Ao contrário do que Jonas comentou, eu em Portugal usei e vi usar o h para significar acento agudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alguns Motivos:

- os teclados em português não eram comuns como hoje em dia. E Mesmo a configuração de idioma não estava sempre disponível nos antigos sistemas operacionais de computadores.
- Pelo fato do H não ter som de nada no português quando usado desta forma. Então convencionou-se esse uso. (Foi muito utilizado nos antigos sistemas de bate-papo.)

Comment: Como curiosidade, no irlandés, quando deixaram de usar o acento punto sobre as consoantes lenitadas, optaram pelo H após a letra base também.  (é dizer, antes escreveram *oíċe*, agora é mais comum *oíche*)

Comment: @guifa  Do you mean Irish Gaelic ?

Comment: Muito provavelmente este uso é uma adaptação do alongamento de vogais de interjeições como ah!

Answer (score 2):

Talvez, pelo fato de que antigamente, quando se enviava mensagens por meio do telex ou telegrama, não se utilizava o acento agudo em determinadas palavras da língua portuguesa ou mesmo em nomes próprios, como por exemplo: estah (está), Canindeh (Canindé), Mossoroh (Mossoró), Itauh (Itaú) etc.. Por essa razão, creio que as pessoas tenham herdado tal hábito obsoleto.